# EV SSL doesn't show green bar

Tags: ssl, apache2, openssl

I've recently installed EV SSL certificate on my site, bought it from GlobalSign.
I followed https://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_apache.php.
Https is working fine, just that green bar doesn't show up.
When I check http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, looks fine. Any Idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had a similar issue on [MiningStockValuator.com](https://miningstockvaluator.com)

The solution was to fix all `src` to only contain data from SSL sources. For instance, jquery should be fetched from `https` and not `http` if you use googleapis.